# $1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1) < (\frac{2n}{e})^{n+1}, n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq 2$ proof doesn't seem to work

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, induction

I found that excercise in an old book without any hint nor solution. Olthough I know a thing ot two about induction, this one seems to be too tricky for me. I know for sure that it's a proof by induction

It is known that: $3e^3 < 64$ (for the base case)
Prove that:

$$1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1) < \left( \frac{2n}{e} \right)^{n+1}, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}, n \ge 2$$

The induction that I am trying to do looks fine in terms of calculations, yet it is not proving anything.

Comment: Do you mean $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \geq 2$?

Comment: It seems the question boils down to showing $$e \le \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1} \left(1 + \frac{1}{2n+1}\right)$$.

Comment: @angryavian Right, and that is true because (1+1/n)^(n+1) is an over approximation of e.

Comment: How did you get that, may I ask?

Comment: @testcase12 Can you show your work with the induction step, to where you're stuck at? It's fine that you can't get it to work out as yet.

Comment: It would be nice if the OP could edit his query to correct the apparent typo's:  the title mentions a factor ($b$) and the query mentions a factor ($a$).  Yet, neither ($a$) nor ($b$) occur in the formula.

Comment: I think now that Bernouli's inequality might work here

Answer (score 1):

Without induction, the problem would be quite simple since you want to prove that
$$\frac{2^n }{\sqrt{\pi }}\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)<\left( \frac{2n}{e} \right)^{n+1}$$ Taking logarithms and using Stirling approximation
$$\log(\text{rhs - lhs})=\left(\log (n)-1+\frac{\log (2)}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{24 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\text{rhs - lhs}=\frac{\sqrt{2} n}{e}+\frac{1}{12 \sqrt{2} e}+\frac{1}{576 \sqrt{2} e
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: Does this asymptotic result actually show the inequality holds for small $n$?

Comment: @angryavian. It works for $n>2$.